# Add more than 1 Suffix to a list of Strings, with the sequence not affected

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, suffix

I have a list of strings:

```py
string = ["banana", "apple", "cat", dog"]
```

and a list of suffix (number of items is not fixed, could be 1, 2 or more):

```py
suffix = ["0422", "1932"]
```

My desire output (order is important and should be the same as the original list):

```py
output = ["banana", "banana0422", "banana1932", "apple", "apple0422", "apple1932", "cat", "cat0422", "cat1932", "dog", "dog0422", "dog1932"]
```

Read through many stack-overflow post but most of them are about adding 1 suffix only, but in my case, there could be 2 or even more suffix. tried itertools.product but still not exactly what i want.

Looking for something smart and effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **List-comprehension**, adding a list with an empty string to `suffix` list

```py
>>> [item+suff for item in string for suff in ['']+suffix]
['banana', 'banana0422', 'banana1932', 'apple', 'apple0422', 'apple1932', 'cat', 'cat0422', 'cat1932', 'dog', 'dog0422', 'dog1932']
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem wasn't the method, but rather adding the no-suffix option, for that add an empty string in front of the other suffixes

```
suffixes = ["0422", "1932"]
[''] + suffixes # ['', '0422', '1932']
```

---

You need 2 for-loops, with classic syntax or inside a list comprehension

```
string = ["banana", "apple", "cat", "dog"]
suffixes = ["0422", "1932"]
result = [word + suffix for word in string for suffix in [''] + suffixes]
```

Works also with `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product
result = list(map("".join, product(string, [''] + suffixes)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` along with `str.join`.

```py
import itertools

fruits = ["banana", "apple"]
suffixes = ["X", "Y"]
output = itertools.product(fruits, [""] + suffixes)  # add empty string to have fruit without suffix
output = map("".join ,output)
output = list(output)
print(output)  # prints ['banana', 'bananaX', 'bananaY', 'apple', 'appleX', 'appleY']
```

---

You can even create function for that

```py
import itertools

def combine(input, suffixes):
    """Adds suffix from suffixes list into each element from input list"""
    if "" not in suffixes:
        suffixes = [""] + suffixes
    output = itertools.product(input, suffixes)
    output = map("".join ,output)
    output = list(output)
    return output
```